# Django model save override not changing self

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm stuck using a non-Django legacy MySQL database. I need to write code that generates a unique filename each time a model object is saved. The following doesn't work. It won't overwrite the filename field. It saves fine with whatever the filename field was set to. Is this because that field is set as the primary key?

(I realize my code isn't creating a random filename--haven't gotten that far yet. Also, I know this will only save once since it needs to be unique, but it won't even save the first time).

```
class Agenda(models.Model):
type = models.IntegerField()
filename = models.CharField(max_length=45, primary_key=True)
date = models.DateField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'gbminutes'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.filename = 'ATESTFILE'
    super(Agenda, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In Django, if you change the value of a primary key field, a copy of the object with the new key will be created.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it. I guess I'll need to do it in the form itself.